# sbt-native-packager rpm brp-java-repack-jars still running despite setting rpmBrpJavaRepackJars to false

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am attempting to build an rpm using sbt-native-packager. It is included in my project like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.0-RC1")
```

and I am kicking off the build process like this:

```
sbt rpm:packageBin
```

The build process is taking a very long time at this point:

```
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
```

I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/195) and tried adding `rpmBrpJavaRepackJars := false` to my `build.sbt` but it doesn't seem to be affecting the rpm build process. Here is what the related section of my build.sbt looks like:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(RpmPlugin)
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm := linuxPackageMappings.value
rpmVendor := "Testing"
rpmGroup := Some("Applications")
rpmUrl := Some("None")
rpmLicense := Some("GPL")
rpmBrpJavaRepackJars := false
```

Am I correctly configuring the rpm plugin and the rpmBrpJavaRepackJars option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in native-packager. Can you open an issue with your description mentioning [this line](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/rpm/RpmPlugin.scala#L112).

`rpmBrpJavaRepackJars` is read from an invalid scope. Try this as a workaround:

```
rpmBrpJavaRepackJars in Rpm := false
```

Definitely a regression.

cheers,
Muki

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you! Opened issue here : https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/789.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/932) to fix this issue. It is fixed as of version [v1.2.0-M8](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/tree/v1.2.0-M8).

So you need:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0-M8")
```

And then

```
rpmBrpJavaRepackJars := false
```

Should work. [It is also the default now](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html#jar-repackaging), so even if you don't set it to `false`, it will skip the RPM repacking.